# Is it possible to run VirtualBox in a Virtuozzo VE

Tags: virtualbox, virtuozzo

I guess this is called Virtualization inside a virtualizer (correct me if I`m wrong).

On my research I found that you need to install on the hardware server of Virtuozzo the option:

```
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_CPU=Y
```

Is it possible to run VirtualBox in a Virtuozzo VE --preferably without adding modules on the hardware node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No

Long answer:
The "Virtualization inside a virtualizer" is called on several google result as "nested virtualization" if you search more reference.

From virtual box documentation(http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#idp12630656):

> VirtualBox uses a special kernel module called vboxdrv to perform
>   physical memory allocation and to gain control of the processor for
>   guest system execution. Without this kernel module, you can still use
>   the VirtualBox manager to configure virtual machines, but they will
>   not start. In addition, there are the network kernel modules
>   vboxnetflt and vboxnetadp which are required for the more advanced
>   networking features of VirtualBox.

In order to use Virtualbox you need to load the vboxdrv, in a Virtuozzo container you can't modify any kernel configuration because the kernel is shared between all the container of the same physical machine.

Comment: [VirtualBox compatibility](http://forum.openvz.org/index.php?t=msg&goto=34609) - according to this post it`s possible.

Comment: @pl1nk The reference you quoted explicitly states that you would need to change the hardware node - the OP explicitly asked for a possibility without modifying the hardware node. It also has a lot of people writing that they had difficulties getting it to work.

Comment: @syneticon-dj I don't disagree however the reference is from January of 2009. It's hard to believe that there are no advancements since ~ 3 years.